# AdMob not loading in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob, adsense

I am trying to implement an AdMob in my app and I am fairly new to this Android Development. 
My requirement is that when the user clicks on a button, a popup dialog should show up which is supposed to have an AdMob and a progress bar below it while my file downloads.

But the issue is that AdMob is not loading at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/bannerAdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_banner_unit" />
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/download_progress_indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/cancel_download_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
  AdView mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.bannerAdView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: " + errorCode);
            downloadFile(view);
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdLoaded: loaded");
            downloadFile(view);
            super.onAdLoaded();
        }
    });
```

As per my code, the download would occur only when either the ad loading is failed or has been completed.

Somehow the line

> ```
> Log.d(TAG, "onAdLoaded: loaded");
> ```

is hit but, the ad is not displayed. can anyone tell me why...and how can I fix it..??

Comment: Try to change  ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE" to ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER".@Vineet Verma.

Answer (score 0):

Is your activity using a dialog theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`  ? If it is, try switching to landscape or use a normal theme and check if the ad shows. If it does, the issue could be that there it not enough room for the ad to show.

You can display the ad in a landscape layout or try changing the ad width to `"wrap_content"` and the size to `"SMART_BANNER"`

Comment: It seems that there was some issue in the google AdMob itself...its now loading quite fine